# Can a symmetric key be safely embedded anywhere in a .NET desktop client program

Tags: .net, secrets-management

Is there a native way, that is, one not requiring the purchase of an expensive third-party obfuscator,  that a .NET desktop client program, deployed to the users' Windows desktops from a LAN server via [ClickOnce](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-security-and-deployment?view=vs-2019), can store a symmetric key without running the risk of that key being obtained by someone with a disassembler tool?  Is there a way to protect a string if it is placed in the `app.config` file?

Comment: Yeah, don't do this. Use asymmetric crypto to safely distribute a public key, which you can then leverage to negotiate a symmetric key. Or use PKI.

Comment: @Pedro: I don't understand what is meant by "negotiate" a symmetric key.

Comment: Instead of having a static symmetric encryption key that is hardcoded somewhere which you then use to decrypt data, you can have a public key or a certificate that you use to establish a secure channel with a known peer, over which you can then negotiate or request a certain key on the fly. It's only an example, depends on your use case, etc.

Comment: Then the question becomes, how/where to keep the public key so that it too stays a secret, since it can be used to obtain the other secret.

Comment: Correct, the difference is that the key is negotiated at run time rather than being statically stored. And you could more easily make it unique per device. If there's encrypted material stored on the device, having the key next to it lets attackers collect it and decrypt stored data.

Answer (score 3):

In such case the application code contains the key and the logic to extract it. An attacker can perform the same steps as the application logic and will extract the key.

Answer (score 3):

No. In fact, there isn't even a way *with* "an expensive third-party obfuscator". If you have an encryption key that you don't want the user to know, you need to do all the decryption on your server.

Comment: When the decryption is done on the server, how is encrypted-in-transit achieved?

Comment: @Tim are you asking how to send data to the user's phone that the user can't read? That's impossible.

Comment: Joseph, to answer you question: No, we have data in the database that needs to be encrypted while  'at rest' and while 'in transit'.  If I understand correctly, the 'in transit' would also mean when traveling between the database server and the user, and I don't see how that can be satisfied unless the desktop software (or the desktop O/S) is where the data gets decrypted. That would mean that the desktop software or the desktop O/S would need access either to a symmetric key or a private asymmetric key. The application is multi-user, and so every user needs to decrypt the data the same way.

Comment: @Tim if you're okay with the user having the data that you send to their phone, then just use TLS like everyone else. Don't try to invent your own thing.

Comment: It is a multi-user desktop app.

Comment: @Tim Okay, to their computer then.